# Como inserir um item numa determinada posição do array php?

Tags: php, array

Tenho o seguinte array,

```
$status = array();
$status["Visualizar"] = "Visualizar";
$status["Editar"] = "Editar";
$status["Status"] = "Alterar Status";
$status["Boleto"] = "Gerar Boleto";
```

Acontece que dependendo do status atual que vai de 1 a 10 devo ou não mostrar o Item $status["Status"], bem com o if resolve, mas acontece que quando dou um unset e depois reinsiro o item ele vai para o final da lista, mas preciso que ele fique na posição original antes de boleto

Exemplo:

```
if ($codstatus == 3){
  $status["Status"] = "Alterar Status";
}else{
  unset($status["Status"]);
}
```

Tem uma forma elegante de fazer isso ou terei que refazer todo o array toda vez?

Comment: Não entendi porque você precisa da posição se a chave da sua matriz é um texto

Comment: É um texto porque num foreach eu listo esse array em um combo pro usuário escolher, por isso deve manter a posição

Comment: Não considero isso um código legal mas talvez te ajude: https://repl.it/Gudr/2
Sugiro que você use somente inteiros para indexar seu array, assim você consegue definir a posição aonde você quer inserir seu texto.

Comment: As vezes temos necessidades de uso por nome nas chaves pra facilitar a leitura em outras partes do código, há uma interação muito grande do sistema com javascript então preciso das chaves com nomes e não números, o que seria inviável lembrar o que cada numero representa. Estou estudando a dica do array_splice

Comment: Não tem mistério, basta verificar no javascript se a chave existe

Answer (score 2):

## Por qual motivo?

Primeiro, por qual motivo você precisa que fique em certa ordem já que seu array é associativo?

Agora, se precisa que fique na ordem correta, você pode utilizar a função `array_splice`, veja exemplo:

```
<?php

$array = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e'];
array_splice($array, 2, 0, 'c');

var_dump($array); //['a','b','c','d','e']
```

Veja exemplo online: https://repl.it/Gudr/0

Comment: O motivo é que há uma interação com javascript onde é feito o uso do nome das keys pra algumas decisões, usar índice numérico é fora de questão, estou tentando usar o array_splice mas não sei se posso inserir um array com nome literar em uma determinada posição, veja 
{
$status = array();
$status["Visualizar"] = "Visualizar";
$status["Editar"] = "Editar";
//$status["Status"] = "Alterar Status";
$status["Boleto"] = "Gerar Boleto";
array_splice($status, 1, 0, array("Status" => "Alterar Status"));
var_dump($status);
}

Answer (score 1):

Faça da seguinte maneira:

```
$status = [
    'Visualizar' => 'Visualizar',
    'Editar' => 'Editar',
    'Boleto' => 'Gerar Boleto'
];

// Define a chave => valor que será inserido no array
$pair = ['Status' => 'Alterar Status'];

// Procura no array pela chave e retorna o índice dela
$afterIndex = array_search('Boleto', array_keys($data));

// Cria um novo array, repartindo o antigo em duas partes e adicionando o novo par de chave => valor entre elas
$newStatus = array_merge(array_slice($status, 0, $afterIndex-1), $pair, array_slice($status, $afterIndex-1));

print_r($newStatus);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [Visualizar] => Visualizar
    [Editar] => Editar
    [Status] => Alterar Status
    [Boleto] => Gerar Boleto
)
```